# STM32F072B-DISCO Example code from manual results error (chapter 7.3.6) with with the "extern TSL_LinRot_T MyLinRots[];

Tags: c, touch, stm32, stm32f0

I am using the STM32F072B-DISCO, trying to implement an example code for the touch sensing and followed the instructions of the "Getting Started with touch sensing Control on STM32 MCU". The code given in chapter 7.2.6 results in errors.

[image: error_code]

Console:

> ../Core/Src/main.c:78:24: error: conflicting types for 'MyLinRots'
> 78 |    extern TSL_LinRot_T MyLinRots[];
> |                        ^~~~~~~~~
> In file included from ../TOUCHSENSING/App/tou

one other error I already removed, was one bracket too much at the end of the example code.

The given example code should be added between the User Code Begin 3 & End which is in the main loop.

Shouldn't be the `extern TSL_LinRot_T MyLinRots[];` outside of the loop? According to the manual, I only have to copy and insert this code and it should work without any edits.

link to manual : [Getting started with touch sensing control on STM32 microcontrollers](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/ed/0d/4d/87/04/1d/45/e5/DM00445657/files/DM00445657.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00445657.pdf)

PS: I do not have a lot of programming experience

Comment: I am not specifically refering to STM devices but unfortunately few things get outdated quicker than sample code for any MCUs. BTW: Your sample looks more like chapter 7.2.6.

Comment: You only show the problem window of your IDE (Looks like Code Composer Studio). I assume you get a more detailled error message in Console window when you compile your code. Does it mention what type was expected?

Comment: yes, you are right, its 7.2.6 I will edit the post.

Comment: I am using the STM32CubeIDE. I will add a picture from the console message

Comment: No, please do not show pictures of text. Instead add it as formatted text in the question.

Comment: Is that really all that is in the console window? Looks to me like you've missed a lot of bits out.

Answer (score -1):

CONST extern TSL_LinRot_T MyLinRots[];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).